# Add class depending on field content with Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have a Vue.js app that displays content pulled from a DB with Axios. A tooltip appears conditionally on certain items depending of the presence of a note for this field in the DB. I'd like to add a class for styling this item if there is a tooltip to display.

Here is what I tried with a computed property.

template:

```
<div class="row">
  <div>{{ brol.name }}</div>
  <div>{{ brol.def }}</div>
  <div :class="[hasRemark ? activeClass : '']" v-b-tooltip.hover :title="('') ? false : brol.note">{{ brol.instit }}</div>
```

(the tooltip works correctly).

data:

```
activeClass: 'aspect',
```

style:

```
.aspect { color: red; }
```

computed:

```
hasRemark() {
   return this.brols.filter(brol => {
    return brol.note !== ' '
   })
 },
```

I can see with a console.log that what I return is an array. But I can't find the right way to modify the property and just get the element and not the whole array to pass it to the ternary condition in the :class props. Is there a proper way to achieve this?

Comment: You want to pass `hasRemark` array to your class?

Comment: no, and that's one of the problems I can't solve. I'd like to match only the ones with a content in the field 'note'. For now, my computed property returns the whole array and I need to filter this. That's where I'm puzzled.

Comment: Hmm... I can not understand your question clearly. Do you mean `:class="[hasRemark ? activeClass : '']"` is not working well? Is it alway return the string `aspect`?

Comment: Yes, it is always returning the string aspect, indeed.

Comment: Maybe you should change it to `hasRemark.length` because `[]` equal `true`

Comment: Yes I changed it to hasRemark.length you're right. But still everything got "aspect". I suppose the logic in the computed is wrong. If I do a console.log with brol.note.length, I see the result for each row with the lengths. But it doesn't apply

Comment: I think `aspect` is the right answer because your filtered array `hasRemark` may always has at least one element. What are you concerning about?

Comment: I will try to be more precise on this point: in the DB, each note has at least one character. I try to apply aspect when the note has more than one. This is why I used the !== '  ' in the computed. Hope it's clearer...

Comment: `more than one`. So i think your computed should be `return brol.note.length > 1`

Comment: I tried that one already but with no success :(